# Scroll lags when using lot of nested divs and overflows

Tags: css, scroll, flexbox, overflow, lag

**Problem**:

I have a table in a modal that has a very laggy scroll behaviour:

[image: scrolllag]

**Testing Environment:**

The scroll issue appears on multiple devices, the screen record was made with:

- MacBook Pro 13", M2, 2022 with Ventura 13.1
- Firefox 109.0.1

I was not able to reproduce the issue with Chrome.

**What I've tried**:

I already tried to remove some css in below example code but without satisfying result. Some of the css is required due to the used framework Bootstrap. Using the dev tools of the browser removes the scroll lag immediately so debugging with the dev tools was no option for me.

Maybe this is related to the firefox hardware acceleration feature? I have checked the option in the settings but without success.

One possible solution at the moment is removing the `overflow-x: auto` of the table wrapper, but I need that one in case the table is too wide for the parent container to support horizontally scrollable table without scrolling the whole parent container.

**Code**:

I already tried to create a code example with minimum amount of code but could not identify the main cause. You can find the reproducable code in jsfiddle:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csxvpt6w/54/)

Kind regards,

Codehardt